# Android + Robolectric - RuntimeException / InstantiationException in queryBuilder.query() in ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, junit, instantiation, robolectric

I have about ten tests on the ContentProvider that just uses SQLite; all pass save the two  that pass through queryBuilder.query() in the Content Provider's query() method.

The methods being tested work in the real application!

This is with API 17 r2 and RoboLectric:
robolectric-2.0-alpha-3-20130417.013705-46-jar-with-dependencies.jar

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "MyContentProvider.query()");
    switch(matcher.match(uri)) {
    case ITEM: // OK
        selection = "_id = ?";
        selectionArgs = new String[]{ Long.toString(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };
    case ITEMS: // OK
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Did not recognize URI " + uri);
    }
    // build the query with SQLiteQueryBuilder
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

    // query the database and get result in cursor
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor resultCursor = qBuilder.query(db,    // Line 112 in trace
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder,
            null);
    resultCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return resultCursor;
}
```

Here's the traceback:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.createShadowFor(ShadowWrangler.java:300)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.initializing(ShadowWrangler.java:74)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.initializing(RobolectricInternals.java:90)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.$$robo$init(SQLiteQuery.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.<init>(SQLiteClosable.java:26)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:41)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:333)
    at com.example.readingsprovider.ReadingsContentProvider.query(ReadingsContentProvider.java:112)
    at com.example.readingsprovider.test.ContentProviderTest.testUpdateMultipleWithoutWhere(ContentProviderTest.java:110)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:267)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:202)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.createShadowFor(ShadowWrangler.java:293)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.initializing(ShadowWrangler.java:74)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.initializing(RobolectricInternals.java:90)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.$$robo$init(SQLiteQuery.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.<init>(SQLiteClosable.java:26)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:41)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.$$robo$$SQLiteDirectCursorDriver_7ac1_query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.$$robo$$SQLiteDatabase_ab15_rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.$$robo$$SQLiteQueryBuilder_ba4d_query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.$$robo$$SQLiteQueryBuilder_ba4d_query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:333)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java)
    at com.example.readingsprovider.ReadingsContentProvider.query(ReadingsContentProvider.java:112)
    at com.example.readingsprovider.test.ContentProviderTest.testUpdateMultipleWithoutWhere(ContentProviderTest.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ... 21 more
```

Can plez tell if this is a limitation of Robolectric, or my bad? Many thanks!

P.S. Wouldn't it be dreamy if the Reflection API would put the failing class name in the InstantiationException message?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue for my projects, and was finally able to solve it with some googling and the previous answer of U Avalos

#### 1. Create custom SQLiteShadow

```java
@Implements(value = SQLiteDatabase.class, inheritImplementationMethods = true)
public class CustomSQLiteShadow extends ShadowSQLiteDatabase {

    @Implementation
    public Cursor rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory,
                                     String sql,
                                     String[] selectionArgs,
                                     String editTable,
                                     CancellationSignal cancellationSignal) {
      return rawQueryWithFactory(cursorFactory,
                                 sql,
                                 selectionArgs,
                                 editTable);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add `@Config` annotation to your test

To use the custom shadow class, you can use the `@Config` annotation in robolectric2

```java
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config( shadows = {CustomSQLiteShadow.class})
public class ContentProviderTest {
```

#### Reference

http://robolectric.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html

Answer (score 2):

Android API 16 introduces this new method (that mtholdefer mentions):

```
public Cursor rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory, String sql, String[] selectionArgs, String editTable, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)
```

As of 7/25/2013, roboelectric does NOT implement this method. However, it implements a similar method that doesn't use a CancellationSignal. Adding this method to ShadowSqlLiteDatabase made the problem go away for me:

```
@Implementation
public Cursor rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory,
                                 String sql,
                                 String[] selectionArgs,
                                 String editTable,
                                 CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)
{
  return rawQueryWithFactory(cursorFactory,
                             sql,
                             selectionArgs,
                             editTable);
}
```

(Yes, you need to have roboelectric as a submodule. )

Comment: Actually you should be able to create a custom shadow class in the test and bind it at run time. However, I haven't figured out how to do that in Roboelectric 2

Answer (score 1):

I have been running into a similar issue and I believe the problem is that SQLiteQueryBuilder is not supported in Robolectric.  You can read more about that [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/70).  Basically the rawQueryWithFactor() method that SQLiteQueryBuilder uses is not overridden in ShadowSQLiteDatabase.  Because of this the cusor is returned as null

I just started instantiating my cursors via SQLiteDatabaseInstance.query and that works perfectly in conjunction with Robolectric. Good luck and let me know if you find a more elegant solution do I can test my queryBuilders as well!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Do you mind sharing a code snippet? If I'm understanding correctly, you rewrote your Android classes to accomodate the unit testing?

Comment: On second thought, why don't you just implement that method? I'm using Roboelectric 2, forked from GitHub, and after implementing the missing method, it worked.

Comment: No I created my cursor in the testing class and skipped testing the code that used queryBuilder.  It was just a small method so it wasn't worth the trouble.  Its definitely worth it to implement rawQueryWithFactory if you use it enough though.