# Robolectric ContentProvider testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have noticed that every now and then there is a question about using Robolectric for testing custom ContentProviders. However, there has never been a concrete and unambiguous answer on how to do it properly. I have stumbled upon 2 different approaches:

- one saying you can simply instantiate an in-memory ContentProvider, which you can use to insert and query data (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6139359)
- the other saying to use the ShadowContentResolver to set mock cursor data (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robolectric/r35mMirIkTs/xJJBNXl_RgwJ)

However, I'm getting a java.lang.InstantiationException with both approaches. There have been some SO posts saying that this is due to SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java) not being overriden in Robolectric ([Android + Robolectric - RuntimeException / InstantiationException in queryBuilder.query() in ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156711/android-robolectric-runtimeexception-instantiationexception-in-querybuilde)).

I guess my question is - are there any preffered workarounds that make testing ContentProviders possible. Or are there any other approaches that are better then those 2 mentioned above.

Comment: I suggest not to use first link at all - code there is completely dumb and won't even compile.

Answer (score 13):

This is the Robolectric (v2.4) test that worked fine for me:

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContentResolver;

import co.tomup.app.db.DbSchema;
import co.tomup.app.db.TomupContentProvider;
import co.tomup.app.db.model.CalendarDay;
import co.tomup.app.db.tables.CalendarDayTable;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class CalendarDayProviderTest {

    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
    private ShadowContentResolver mShadowContentResolver;
    private TomupContentProvider mProvider;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mProvider = new TomupContentProvider();
        mContentResolver = Robolectric.application.getContentResolver();
        mShadowContentResolver = Robolectric.shadowOf(mContentResolver);
        mProvider.onCreate();
        ShadowContentResolver.registerProvider(DbSchema.AUTHORITY, mProvider);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertAndDelete() {
        // insert
        CalendarDay calendarDay = new CalendarDay();
        calendarDay.setId(1L);
        calendarDay.setDay(new LocalDate());
        calendarDay.setMoonPhase("new");
        calendarDay.setSunrise(1);
        calendarDay.setSunset(100);
        Uri insertionId = mContentResolver.insert(CalendarDayTable.CONTENT_URI,
                calendarDay.toSQLiteContentValues());
        Cursor cursorCheck = mShadowContentResolver.query(CalendarDayTable.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        while (cursorCheck.moveToNext()) {
            CalendarDay calendarDayCheck = CalendarDay.fromSQLiteCursor(cursorCheck);
            assertEquals(calendarDay, calendarDayCheck);
        }
        assertTrue(cursorCheck.getCount() > 0);
        // delete
        mShadowContentResolver.delete(insertionId,
                null, null);
        cursorCheck = mShadowContentResolver.query(CalendarDayTable.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        assertTrue(cursorCheck.getCount() == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am relying more on learning Android using robolectric. I get tired of going back and forth with the emulator. And this answer is helping me to user and test contentprovider. :)

Comment: Note this answer is for RoboElectric 2.4, if you are using 3.0 then use https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide to find the 3.0 equivalents.

Comment: @Benjamin do you know if there's an example using 3.0?  Are the only changes you have to make are to the class & annotation names?  Here's are the changes I've interpreted from the document --> change the test runner to RoboelectricGradleTestRunner, and maybe change getApplication to getShadowApplication.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do, is set up `ShadowContentResolver` before test, so it will properly associate authority of your `ContentProvider` with `ContentProvider` itself. Here is an example:

```
ShadowContentResolver.registerProvider(
        "com.example.provider",    //authority of your provider
        contentProvider    //instance of your ContentProvider (you can just use default constructor)    
);
```

The easiest way is to put this stuff into some `@Before` annotated set-up method. However, the more correct (and therefore better in long term) way is to put this into your `TestApplication#onCreate` method, so this configuration will be used by all tests in your application.

Comment: I put the above code into `TestApplication#onCreate` but it couldn't use the content provider for all tests. After the first test the database will be removed: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1082 . Did you success to have more than 2 tests for content provider with Robolectric?

Comment: @HieuRocker yes, I do. If I understood you correctly, then you got it a bit wrong - that should be expected behavior for tests to clean up after execution. Just create your database each time in some `@Before` method

Comment: W00t, I could fix the issue based on your hint. Turned out it was because in the ContentProvider, I initialized `SQLiteOpenHelper` using singleton pattern. It causes Robolectric failed to recreate the database for each test. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Using Roboelectric 4.2, this is what worked for me:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyContentProviderTest {

    private ContentResolver contentResolver;
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        repository = mock(MyRepository.class);
        contentResolver = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

        ProviderInfo info = new ProviderInfo();
        info.authority = "my.authority";
        info.grantUriPermissions = true;
        ContentProviderController<MediaContentProvider> controller = Robolectric
                .buildContentProvider(MyContentProvider.class)
                .create(info);

        MyContentProvider provider = controller.get();
        // Method in my ContentProvider that allows to override
        // the repository it uses
        provider.setRepository(repository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuery() {

        // setup expectations in mockito
        when(repository.getAll()).thenReturn(...);

        try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(SOME_URI, null, null, null, null)) {
            // test cursor contents here
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **Wim Deblauwe**'s answer, I have also done with **roboelectric 4.2** in **Kotlin**
, Here is the full demonstration:

#### this is my custom provider class

```kotlin
    //this is my custom provider class    
    public final class NameProvider : ContentProvider() {
        private var pContext: Context? = null;
        private var nameDbHelper: NameDbHelper? = null
        private var dataBase: SQLiteDatabase? = null
        private val Log_Tag = "NAME_PROVIDER"
        
        override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
            pContext = context
            nameDbHelper = pContext?.let { NameDbHelper(it) }
            dataBase = nameDbHelper?.writableDatabase
            if (dataBase == null) {
                Log.d(Log_Tag, "dataBase NOT created ...")
                return false
            }
            Log.d(Log_Tag, "dataBase created ...")
            return true
        }
    
        override fun query(p0: Uri, p1: Array<out String>?, p2: String?, p3: Array<out String>?, p4: String?): Cursor? {
            var queryBuilder : SQLiteQueryBuilder = SQLiteQueryBuilder()
            queryBuilder.tables = "TABLE_NAME"
            val cursor = queryBuilder.query(dataBase,p1,p2,p3,null,null, "COLUMN_NAME")
            cursor.setNotificationUri(pContext?.contentResolver, p0)
            return cursor
        }
    
        override fun insert(p0: Uri, p1: ContentValues?): Uri? {
            val rowID: Long? = dataBase?.insert("TABLE_NAME", "", p1)
            rowID?.let {
                if (it > 0) {
                    val _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, it)
                    pContext?.contentResolver?.notifyChange(_uri, null)
                    return _uri
                }
            }
            throw SQLException("Failed to add a record into")
        }
        
        override fun getType(p0: Uri): String? {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    
        override fun delete(p0: Uri, p1: String?, p2: Array<out String>?): Int {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    
        override fun update(p0: Uri, p1: ContentValues?, p2: String?, p3: Array<out String>?): Int {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
```

#### this is my test class with roboelectric

```kotlin
    @Config(maxSdk = 29)
    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
    class NameProviderTest {
    
        private var contentResolver : ContentResolver? = null
        private var shadowContentResolver : ShadowContentResolver? = null
        private var nameProvider : NameProvider? = null
        
        @Before
        fun setUp() {
            contentResolver = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().contentResolver
            val providerInfo : ProviderInfo = ProviderInfo()
            providerInfo.authority = NameContract.AUTHORITY
            providerInfo.grantUriPermissions = true
            val controller = Robolectric.buildContentProvider(NameProvider::class.java).create(providerInfo)
            shadowContentResolver = shadowOf(contentResolver)
            nameProvider = controller.get()
    
        }
    
        @Test
        fun onCreate() {
            val res  = nameProvider?.onCreate()
            assertEquals(res, true)
            //ShadowContentResolver.registerProviderInternal(NameContract.AUTHORITY, nameProvider)
        }
    
        @Test
        fun query() {
            val values =  ContentValues()
            values.put(NameContract.KEY_NAME, "ABCD")
            val uri = contentResolver?.insert(NameContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
            assertNotNull(uri)
            val cursor = contentResolver?.query(NameContract.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null)
            assertNotNull(cursor)
            var name : String? = null
            if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NameContract.KEY_NAME))
            }
            cursor?.close()
            assertNotNull(name)
            assertEquals(name, "ABCD")
        }
        
        @Test
        fun insert() {
            val values =  ContentValues()
            values.put(NameContract.KEY_NAME, "Taher")
            val uri = contentResolver?.insert(NameContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
            assertNotNull(uri)
    
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a pull request for robolectic which adds a replacement for ProviderTestCase2: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/2060.